# Can't send an attachment loaded into HTML

Tags: c#, html, dreamweaver

I have been trying to figure this out but I am so lost.  I am not a web design guru by any means.  I know enough to get by but we have an internal intranet site where we fill out text fields and when submit is pressed it generates an email and sends it to specific people.  I want to integrate attachments but nothing I try is working.  What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" multiple runat="server" />
```

C#

```
public partial class it_support_request : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String toAddress = ""; 
        String fromAddress = userid.Text.Trim() + "@company.com";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.company.com");
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        try
        {   
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            message.Subject = "IT Support Request: " + this.subjectBox.Text;
            message.Body = "From: " + nameBox.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Created At: " + txtDate.Text + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Department: " + listDepartment.SelectedItem.Text  + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Priority: " + listPriority.SelectedItem.Text  + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Issue Type: " + listIssueType.SelectedItem.Text + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Machine Area: " + txtcomputernum.Text + "\n" + "\n";
            message.Body += "Problem description: " + txtQuestion1.Text;
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
            }
            toAddress += "user@company.com";
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display error panel
            formPanel.Visible = false;
            errorPanel.Visible = true;
        }
        formPanel.Visible = false;
        errorPanel.Visible = false;
        successPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void ResetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listPriority.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listIssueType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtcomputernum.Text = "";
        nameBox.Text = "";
        subjectBox.Text = "";
        txtQuestion1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I am trying to attach a very small file and send it.  I get the message that the email has bent successfully but nothing actually comes in.

Changes to message.body lines to get to email all but attachment:

```
        message.Body = "From: " + nameBox.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Created At: " + txtDate.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Department: " + listDepartment.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()  + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Priority: " + listPriority.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()  + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Issue Type: " + listIssueType.SelectedItem.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Machine Area: " + txtcomputernum.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Problem description: " + txtQuestion1.Text.Trim()
```

Comment: Every time someone writes a silent `catch` block, god kills a kitten.

Comment: check Junk Mail folder?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code..? also try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288832/unable-to-send-e-mail-with-attachment if this doesn't help do some google searching. also I would suggest if you are going to use `IsBodyHtml`, that you use a string builder to build the message content along with html tags if necessary.

Comment: Did you set your form's `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: It does not show in my junk folder and i have tried the other suggestion and still does not work

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing: without files it does send well, and with files it does send but never arrives at the inbox?

Comment: I get nothing wether the file is attached or not.  If I remove the CS with the attachment data and the file upload line in the html then I get the email just fine.

Comment: Ok I got it to work to the point where no matter if there is something in the attachment field or not it will email everything except for the attachment

Comment: @Individual101 so what were your changes?

Comment: I had to put .Trim() at the end of the message.body lines.  I added it to the bottom of the original post

Comment: So I still don't get attachments.  Any idea's?